# How can I iterate through a drop-down list and click on each and every option? Getting StaleElementReferenceException error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using this code but I got clicked limited options in result after that it throws the error given below.

I want to click through all options, but I don't understand why it is happening. I have 50 options in my dropdown.

```
select = Select(wait(driver, 35).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('BodyContent__company')))

options = select.options

for opt in options:
    # for example
    print(opt.text)
    opt.click()
```

> Error: StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference:
> element is not attached to the page document(Session info:
> chrome=83.0.4103.116)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With every click on the `select` element's options, the element (`select`) updates. That is why the `StaleElementReferenceException` error - the element has changed.

Try this. After identifying `select`, click all options using their index. After each click re-identify `select` to avoid Stale Element Reference Exception.

```
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 35).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'BodyContent__company'))))    

for index in range(len(select.options)):
    select.select_by_index(index)
    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 35).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'BodyContent__company'))))
```

You will need these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
```

Comment: Problem is not solved...I am attaching the link may be u could help me in better way..I am new to this..The link is https://www.transferofvalue.ie/ToVData/AME

Comment: i am getting same error when i minimize my chrome but when i let my chrome opened it is running perfectly..Thank u for your solution because i  don't understand that point that it should remain open because i am new that this ..May be it is limitation that it should remain open but i don't know the reason behind it..

Comment: If you want it to run in the background, research "headless" mode. It's an option you can configure for your selenium controlled browser, that will run the script without popping up a browser window.